# Get apache linux user from php

Tags: php, apache

I'm on a foreign linux system and need to determine the user that apache runs on (and so does php).

The aim:
I need to get the owner of the script (this is no problem as I can use SplFileInfo) and compare it to the owner of the apache process.

I'm open to any alternative proposals.

Regards,
Mario

Edit:
Additional info:

The script is a thumbnail generator, that uses an XML file to generate thumbs from larger images. The script needs to create folders and write files. As I cannot influence the php configuration and I do not have any shell access, this has to be done very silently. 
The creation process stopps via exception and sends a mail on failue. As most of php's function cannot throw exceptions on failue, I need some manual checks to determine the environment I'm in. Therefore I need the apache user to compare it to some directory or fileowner.

Comment: As option you can simply use /tmp, that is writeable for everyone.

Comment: Thats not useful for our case, as we cannot serve any generated images from outside the docroot.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can call the php [exec](http://php.net/exec) function to execute *whoami*:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Comment: thanx grant! thanx to the anon.,

both methods provided here are very well suited. I will use grant's method, as I cannot assert that the posix function are available.

Comment: exec() won't work if safe_mode is enabled and whoami is outside of safe_mode_exec_dir.

Comment: absolutely correct, but for my target environment this is the best solution. (no safe_mode ;))

Comment: This works for **linux** and **unix**, I haven't tested it for **windows** though.

Comment: I just tested this on Windows (XAMPP) and surprisingly it works, returning in my case `msedgewin10\ieuser` which is `machine_name\user_name`. I then went and tried typing on a simple DOS prompt `whoami` and it worked the same. Cool.

Answer (score 8):

see posix_getuid() and posix_getpwuid()

Answer (score 5):

Some complicated answers here.

This works for me:

```
$user = getenv('APACHE_RUN_USER');
```

Not sure if this is just a new thing that been added to apache since this question was asked but it's definitely there now.

Comment: In my case, it didn't work. It just returned an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

[phpinfo](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) will dump a lot of system information.  For apache2 installs, there is a section that displays the apache user and group ids.  Try creating a php script that just has one line, a call to phpinfo(), and open it in your web browser.

Comment: Thats not the aim ;)
I know how to get the user via php info ... i need to aquire the names as strings from within a script.

Comment: ... and parsing the phpinfo(INFO_MODULES) is NOT an alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some php script **must** be run on apache user (cli), whoami is not appropriate in that case.
Here is my solution :

```
$output = exec('apachectl -S 2>/dev/null | grep User');
$apacheUser = preg_match('/name="([^"]+)"/', $output, $match) ? $match[1] : 'www-data';
```