# Can I find which user the web server is being run as in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I'm writing a simple web app in PHP that needs to have write access to a directory on the server, if the directory isn't writable I want to display an error message explaining to set the owner of the directory to whoever the webserver is being run as (eg. www-data, nobody) but as most people don't know this it would be nice to be able to tell them who to chown the directory to. Is it possible to find this from PHP?

Comment: This is a very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805907/get-apache-linux-user-from-php.  You might find your answer there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [shell_exec()](http://www.php.net/shell_exec)

Answer (score 19):

```
<?php
  echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Comment: I'm using that but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Late, but you need to pass a second parameter to capture output.
```exec($cmd, $out);var_dump($out);```

Answer (score 4):

If on linux/unix:

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner($temp)));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The quick-and-dirty trick I use is to write a file to `/tmp/`. It should be created with the user and group used by the PHP process.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix platforms, this solution might work even with safe mode on, provided that the posix extension is installed or compiled in.

```
$user = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo $user['name'];
```

Docs are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you can run some bash, you can use `whoami` or you might be able to poke around in `/proc`

Answer (score 0):

That error message falls apart in a windows server environment.  "Please make sure the web server has write access to the directory" is probably a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

In some servers using `echo exec('whoami');` or  `exec('whoami',$out); echo $out;`
returns nothing but in every situation you can get the current user with [get_current_user](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)

```
<?php
echo get_current_user();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows system to test on - but under Unix-likes, [get_current_user()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) returns the expected username (the user running the web server).