# PHP Upload dir other than web root (htdocs) folder?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is it possible to change the upload dir to some other in PHP other than htdocs folder? As I don't want my files to be exposed to web directly. Can it be done? I am using my Desktop as upload location, but files are not getting uploaded here! Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
            $errors= array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
            $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

            $expensions= array("txt");      
            if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
                $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
            }
            if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
            }               
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/home/abhi/Desktop/uploads/".$file_name);
                echo "Success";
            }else{
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: is the folder is accessible by app ? (abhi abhi hindi movie song)

Comment: yes anywhere you want outside theyour public dir

Comment: @BhavinRana its localhost, I guess must be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. The folder you save it into must have the correct permissions from the "user" running the webserver. Take a look at [Can I find which user the web server is being run as in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827327/can-i-find-which-user-the-web-server-is-being-run-as-in-php)