# Python file cannot run through PHP button

Tags: python, php

I have below PHP file which is use to run python file as below..

```
<?php

$file_path = '/root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python3 /home/svradmin/scripts/testupdate.py';
$command = escapeshellcmd($file_path);
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;     

 ?>
```

when I run `php testfile.php` this works fine.. But when I call this through a button as below this is not working(python is inserting a current timestamp when It has executed)..

Here is my button..

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN"  /><br/>
</form>

<?php

function testrun()
{

$file_path = '/root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python3 /home/svradmin/Performence_Analytics/scripts/testupdate.py 2>&1';

$command = escapeshellcmd($file_path);
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
}

if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   testrun();
}

?>
```

Can someone show me where I made the wrong? I checked error logs as well.. But there is no any error log as well..

update:

For testing purpose I made the whole path to 777 permission and updated the script with environment variables as well. But still have the issue..

```
putenv("cd /home/svradmin/scripts/");
putenv("TEMP=/home/svradmin/tmp");
putenv("PATH=/root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin");
$file_path = 'python3 /home/svradmin/scripts/testupdate.py';

$command = escapeshellcmd($file_path);
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
```

Comment: `root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python3` may not be available to PHP process!

Comment: Thanx...is there anyway to make it available?

Comment: PHP runs as a user on the system. When you run a CLI, PHP runs as you with your permissions and environment variables. When you run it through a web server there’s a different user and environment variables. Find the user, adjust the permissions and look for any environment variables that are needed

Comment: So it works on command line (root?) but not through a webserver with a browser, right? Most likely the webserver's user cannot access the path. Those both shell functions are considered unsecure and vulnerable, by the way.

Comment: I used below solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827327/can-i-find-which-user-the-web-server-is-being-run-as-in-php to find the php user. It shows as **root**

Comment: php user is usually www-data. Test it out by running a (looping or long running) script and look with ps.

Comment: php user as root - surely not from the webserver's side (ie. run from a browser)? You, on the terminal command line, and the web server are most likeley, hopefully, running as different users from the system's perspective. Apache, for example, usually runs as "apache", "http", or "wwwdata", etc user, while you might be logged in as "root" personally.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, sorry I didnt get what you mean.. need to locate the python script in var/www/ ?

Comment: No, you should know which user the php process is to grant execution of the python interpreter. php is **not** runing as root.

Comment: shell_exec( 'whoami' ); prints user as root.. Any method to find that?  @MarkusZeller

Comment: Yes, I told you. `php user is usually www-data. Test it out by running a (looping or long running) script and look with ps.`

Comment: If you run from terminal, it runs as you, the logged in user. If you run from web, it runs as the webserver user.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanx.. my user is apache.... So I need to adjust execution permission to root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python3 path for apache user?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I made some changes and put 777 as permission for the whole path(for test only) and included env variables as well. But still have the issue.. Could you please kindly comment it now

Comment: `putenv("cd /home/svradmin/scripts/");` looks strange, do you mean `chdir("/home/svradmin/scripts/");`? Also the apache user needs to have access to that directory.