# Moodle 2.5 (openSuse) cron job stopped running, I can't find it, or logs, where is Moodle's cron?

Tags: linux, apache, cron, moodle, opensuse

I had a Moodle 2.3 installation, that was running fine.
Upgraded to Moodle 2.5, now the notifications page says Cron job not run in 24 hrs.

So, the cron stopped running.
I ran it via a browser/URL and it took a while and never finished, the server froze and I had to restart it.  I'm assuming this isn't supposed to happen, but I have been afraid of running cron again.

Now, Where do I see the cron jobs?  how can I see if a cron job is already there but stopped running,  where can I find the logs,  which user would this cron be run under?

This is an openSuse server

I tried these commands:

1. `crontab -u apache2 -e`
2. `crontab -u apache -e`
3. `crontab -u www-data -e`
4. `crontab -u root -e`   <- this opens a new file and says one doesn't exist so one will be created.

None of them work.

Please help me find any existing cron jobs, logs, what the cron user for moodle 2.5 would be (it's not `root`, `apache`, `www-data` etc), I'd like to see why they stopped or so I can turn them back ok some how.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Check the web server's user

Normally cron jobs are run using the same user of the web server (to find out: [Get apache linux user from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805907/get-apache-linux-user-from-php?lq=1)). On debian-like distribution is `www-data`, on OpenSuse I think it's **`wwwrun`**.

### 2. Check the cron jobs defined

After that, you can check the cron jobs like you already said (anyway, Moodle doesn't define cron jobs at installation, it's possible that they were not defined beforehand, or something or someone removed the jobs?)

```
$ sudo crontab -u wwwrun -e
```

or:

```
$ sudo -u wwwrun crontab -e
```

Usually a Moodle cron job look similar to a line like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null
```

But it could also be listed in a file (read carefully [Cron on Moodle Wiki](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Cron)).

### 3. Check if the cron job is working

For checking if cron is working look at this: [Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work?lq=1).

### Notes

I would be careful before setting the cronjob, if it could kill your server.. :) I would try to directly run the script from the commandline, to see if everything would work ok. Something like this:

```
sudo -u wwwrun /usr/bin/php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php
```

Comment: not wwwrun, the user exists, but i get the same message i get when i use root. Command: sudo -u wwwrun crontab -e  
Output:
no crontab for wwwrun - using an empty one

Comment: that link you posted to figure out who the user is, isnt helping me, it shows php commands, how do i run PHP on shell? i dont know

Comment: Well, you have to find out the user of Apache. So it would be useless to run it in a shell. You have to put the content in a file like `foo.php`, in the `DocumentRoot` of apache (`/srv/www/htdocs/`, on your distribution I think), and then run it `domain-of-your-server.com/foo.php`, or `ip-of-your-server/foo.php`.