# How to solve a Linux permission issue for opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I had used subversion to revert my PHP Opencart project, but I got a permission issue (sample shown below:

> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open '/var/www/html/opencart/image/cache/data/pavblog/img-blog-620x300w.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/html/opencart/system/library/image.php on line 45
>
> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open '/var/www/html/opencart/image/cache/data/pavblog/img-blog-250x250w.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/html/opencart/system/library/image.php on line 45
>
> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open...

I executed the below commands to add permissions to these folders, but I'm still getting the warning messages on my site.

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/opencart
cd /var/www/html/opencart 
sudo chmod 777 image/ 
sudo chmod 777 image/cache/ 
sudo chmod 777 image/data/ 
sudo chmod 777 system/cache/ 
sudo chmod 777 system/logs/ 
sudo chmod 777 download/ 
sudo chmod 777 config.php
sudo chmod 777 admin/config.php
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you do `ls -al` in one of the folders, who is shown as the file owner: root, www-data, apache, or someone else?

Comment: the owner is root for all folders and files.

Comment: Alright...that's almost certainly the real issue. I'm going to refer you to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30888/47521, since that will better describe proper file permissions

Comment: thanks, problem sloved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply permissions recursively. Try

`sudo chmod -R 777 image/cache/`

Comment: You have a good point about using recursion, but I'm _really_ leery about granting executable permission to anyone.

Comment: Agreed, 777 should never be used in my opinion, just following your example. Try 644 first, then 755 if that didn't work. (hard to tell what you need without knowing your full setup)

Answer (score 11):

To fix your permissions, you'll need to take two different steps:

1. Grant permission to the proper entity. Since you're in /var/www/html, my guess is that the correct user is "apache".

   ```
   # Grants permissions to apache
   sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/opencart

   # If that doesn't work, perhaps try www-data
   sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/opencart
   ```
2. Set the permissions of files and folders properly (it can be dangerous for files to have execute permission)

   ```
   # Sets directory permissions to 755 (rwxr-xr-x)
   sudo find /var/www/html/opencart -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

   # Sets file permissions to 644 (rw-r--r--)
   sudo find /var/www/html/opencart -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
   ```

Comment: Find the apache user: `$user = getenv('APACHE_RUN_USER');` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415081/560287