# Can't Login to Open Cart website

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am not  able to login to opencart website

when i enter username and passoword.  url becomes like this

and nothing happens

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=9d2ea990e9612a5d3a8fc9fe4cf8c55a
```

Even i had tried with wrong password as well. No Error message

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: Are you running it on linux machine with no permission ?

Comment: it is hosted on Bluehost.  what do u mean by no permission ?

Comment: In the cpanel, you can see the `permission` as one of the attribute in the list screen .. something like `777` or `655` .. It should be there for files and folders in your cpanel.

Comment: Permission are 0644 for files and 0755 for folders

Comment: It is in the install.txt file of your open cart and here's a question which deals about it. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26551819/3282633) and [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3882&start=0) You should check whether you have proper permission for those files and folders.

Comment: File Permissions are proper

Comment: Have you set the `url` for admin in the config (There will be two config file to be changed) ??

Answer (score 1):

You should define the url for admin and general in two seperate config.php file

For the general config the `config.php` will be in the root folder

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://192.168.1.someiporaddress/yourdomain/');
```

And for Admin the config file will be inside the `admin` folder

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://192.168.1.someiporaddress/yourdomain/admin/');
```

Note :

To debug use the below codes to your `php.ini` inside your `system/settings` folder

```
display_errors = 1;
error_reporting = E_ALL;
log_errors = 1;
```

and also in the error_log which is inside `system/logs/error.log`

Comment: I mgetting log error like


2015-04-09 2:54:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: thisishome in /home/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_limeapple_template_common_header.tpl on line 24

Comment: Yes, then that's the error, you have missed out in the `vq2-catalog_view_theme_limeapple_template_common‌​_header.tpl`  the variable `thisishome` is being used without declaration

Comment: How to fix this error. there are lots of stuff showing like ths.  few dasy back it was working fine

Comment: i also tried print_r($_session). only i ma getting Array
(
    [currency] => CAD
)
/h

Comment: No . there is no any other variable

Comment: It should be solved step by step then, can you first check on the `.tpl` file whether you declared the variable `thisishome` there ?

Answer (score 0):

You've likely got a php or MySQL error that's preventing the page from loading.  Check in `system/logs/error.txt` and/or your webserver error log to see what's causing it.